# How create a background service to upload bulk files to amazon s3 with node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I want to create a service which pick bulks files one by one from local user machine and upload it on amazon s3 server and return files hash and location address which later i will be saving in mongodb database.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Enumerating a list of files?  Integrating the AWS SDK?  Connecting to MongoDB?

Comment: Hi Brad, To explain the situation further--- When user click on upload he will select a excel file which will contain 1000+ records, in these records every record will have a file path where a pdf file is stored in local folder. Service should pick records and respective pdf file from local machine and upload it to s3 server and the response which came from s3 will be saved into mongodb server with excel data records. Now what will be best flow of code to achieve this? Please help!

Comment: Ok, but what *specific* part of the problem are you having trouble with?  On Stack Overflow, you must ask one specific question at a time.  This isn't a free coding consulting service, nor a free developer service.  This is a place where people break their problems down into small pieces, and others help teach them.  That way, you have a chance of learning how to do these things yourself later and teaching others.  Additionally, others who come by later may find your question/answer useful.